# jQuery: Best way to append to html of a paragraph inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, paragraph

I have a textarea that contains variable html content which is always wrapped in a paragraph (p) tag.

**HTML (before appending):**

```
<textarea rows='7' class='form-control' id='comments'><p>My variable HTML content.</p></textarea>
```

I fetch this content using the following in jQuery:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#comments').val();
```

Now I need to append HTML at the end of this paragraph but inside the p tag.

**HTML (after appending):**

```
<textarea rows='7' class='form-control' id='comments'><p>My variable HTML content. Some appended HTML.</p></textarea>
```

I can of course replace the last 4 characters of the above (which is the closing p tag), then append my HTML and then add the closing p tag again. 
Can someone tell me if there is a better way to achieve the same in jQuery ?

Many thanks in advance for this, Tim.

Comment: I'm not sure why you put a `p` tag inside a textarea, but if you want to append to the `p` but not the textarea then just select what's in the `p`: `$('#comments p').val()`;

Comment: Thanks, the p tag gets added automatically as I use a text editor on this textarea.

Comment: There is no `p` tag. You can't have any tag in a textarea: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/rfkgzjms/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse the string value of the textarea as HTML, and insert whatever you like, then pass the string value of the HTML back

```
$('#comments').val(function(_, val) {
    return $('<div />', {html:val}).find('p').append('content').end().html();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/psowa0sn/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's exactly what I was looking for. Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Answer (score 2):

This could do the trick

```
var html = $('#comments').val();
$('#comments').val(
    $(html).append('  Some appended HTML.')[0].outerHTML
);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Le3uhLjy/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I REALLY love this!

```
$('#comments').text($($('#comments').text()).append(' a new insert!').text());
```

Don't look at it too long. Could hurt your eyes :-)

Comment: Thanks. This won't work as the p tag is within the textarea so it doesnt have its own id.

Comment: I tried it. It works. It just remove the <p> If you are attached to them, you allways can do `$('#comments').text('<p>' + $($('#comments').text()).append(' a new insert!').text() + '</p>');`

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the value into a temporary div, add an element to the `<p>`-element inside the temporary div and fetch the renewed content again:

```
var tmpDiv = $('<div></div>'); //create temporary element
tmpDiv.html($('#comments').val()); // add HTML from textarea
$(someHtml).appendTo($('p', tmpDiv)); // append custom HTML to P inside temp element
newTextAreaValue = tmpDiv.html(); // retrieve new value
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this will work as the p tag is within the textarea so it doesnt have its own id.